# Change subcategory URL(slug) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, slug

I have problem with slug(URL) in category/subcategory. Now i have: http://my-page.pl/animal-category/animal-subcategory. How can i delete "animal-category" for every subcategory ?

It should look like that:

http://my-page.pl/animal-category/

http://my-page.pl/animal-subcategory/

http://my-page.pl/animal-subcategory/single-page

Maybe it's simple question, but I cant find answer anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code it will help you

```
   // Add 'cat_redirect' query variable in query_vars
    add_filter('query_vars', 'no_parent_cat_query_vars');
    function no_parent_cat_query_vars($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'cat_redirect';
        return $query_vars;
    }
    // Redirect if 'cat_redirect' is set
    add_filter('request', 'no_parent_cat_request');
    function no_parent_cat_request($query_vars) {

        if(isset($query_vars['cat_redirect'])) {
            $cat_link = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $query_vars['cat_redirect'], 'category' );
            status_header(301);
            header("Location: $cat_link");
            exit();
        }
        return $query_vars;
    }

     // Remove category 
    add_filter('category_link', 'category_url_without_parent',1000,2);
    function category_url_without_parent($cat_link, $cat_id) 
    {
            $category = &get_category( $cat_id );
             if ( is_wp_error( $category ) ) return $category;

            $catname = $category->slug;

            $cat_link = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $catname, 'category' );
            return $cat_link;
     }

    // Add custom category rewrite rule
    add_filter('category_rewrite_rules', 'remove_category_parent_rule');
    function remove_category_parent_rule($cat_rewrite) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $cat_rewrite=array();
        $cat_list=get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>false));
        foreach($cat_list as $category) {
            $catname = $category->slug;
            $cat_rewrite['('.$catname.')/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
            $cat_rewrite['('.$catname.')/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
            $cat_rewrite['('.$catname.')/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]';
        }

        $old_base = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();
        $old_base = str_replace( '%category%', '(.+)', $old_base );
        $old_base = trim($old_base, '/');
        $cat_rewrite[$old_base.'$'] = 'index.php?cat_redirect=$matches[1]';

        return $cat_rewrite;
    }
```